# set Store View to operate on

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

How would you make sure your code consistently changes attributes (or perform any other operations) on one Store View?

I have "All Store View", "Default Store View" and "Wholesale Store View".

is there some Magento PHP code to do that? something like:

```
->setCurrentStoreView("WHOLESALE_STORE_VIEW");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is: `->setCurrentStore('YOUR_STORE_ID');`

`YOUR_STORE_ID` will be your store view code.  You can change this anywhere in your php with `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('YOUR_STORE_ID');`